# Android socket client works on Java server but not C# server

Tags: c#, android, sockets

I'm new to Android programming and I'm trying to send some text data to PC via TCP.

I built an example I found on the web, which has an Android Client and a Java Server.

The server runs ok.

When I run the Android Client on the emulator or on the phone, both works perfectly well.

The problem is that I need it to communicate to a C# application, so I built an TCP server in C#.

Now, if I run the Client on the emulator it works and the C# server receive the data (a little messed, but it's probably an text encoding problem which I think won't be hard to solve). But anyway, the data is arriving at the c# server.

If I try to run the same Client on the phone I can't even connect to the C# server. I get a timeout error when connecting.

Also I can ping the PC from phone and ping the phone from PC, so I don't think it's a network problem.

I have some experience in C# but not much on sockets and even less on Android. So I ask, is there any difference on TCP protocols used by Java and C#? Sorry if it's a dumb question, but I googled it for hours and haven't found a clue.

Any ideas of what may be causing it?

The Java server code is this:

```
public class Servidor {
private static boolean executando = true;
private static String mensagem;
private static final int PORTA = 1234;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1234);
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println("----------- SERVER CONNECTED "
                + addr.getHostAddress() + " PORT " + PORTA
                + " -----------");
        System.out.println("Waiting connections.");

        Socket socket = server.accept();

        System.out.println("Server -> Connected Ip "
                + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        try {
            while (executando) {
                mensagem = in.readUTF();
                System.out.println("Server-> Received Message: "
                        + mensagem);
            }
            System.out.println("Servidor-> Finalizado.");

            in.close();
            socket.close();
            server.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Server -> Error: " + e.getMessage());
            executando = false;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} }
```

The C# Server code is this:

```
class Server
{
    private TcpListener tcpListener;
    private Thread listenThread;

    public Server()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nStarting server...");

        this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
        this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
        this.listenThread.Start();
    }

    private void ListenForClients()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nWaiting for clients to connect...");

        this.tcpListener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            blocks until a client has connected to the server
            TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

            create a thread to handle communication
            with connected client
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
            clientThread.Start(client);
        }
    }

    private void HandleClientComm(object client)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nIncoming from client...");

        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                blocks until a client sends a message
                bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
            }
            catch
            {
                a socket error has occured
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                the client has disconnected from the server
                break;
            }

            message has successfully been received
            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
            Console.WriteLine("\nReceived: \n\n" + encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
        }

        tcpClient.Close();
    }
}
```

If needed, the Android Client code is exactly the one on the following link:

http://www.portalandroid.org/comunidade/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=11077&p=127577

Comment: `this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
        this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.172"), 1234);` why you setting tcpListener twice ?

Comment: The 2nd line doesn't exist, yesterday night on a last try I tried to hard-code the phone IP to see if it could connect and it didn't work and I forgot to remove it. Code is edited to what it really is.

Comment: so first debug C# code ... instead of empty catch try to log exception ... then check if `Read(message, 0, 4096)` not returns 0 ...  im not sure if this `Read` is blocking or not ... so if it is not blocking it could return 0 if there is no data available.

Comment: @Selvin The code doesn't get to the try/catch and Read lines. The client doesn't even connect to the server, because it does not print the "Incoming from client" message

Comment: Thank you all people... I finally did solve this. I had to create an exception on firewall to all local ports. I didn't made it before because It was working on the Java server, so I thought the firewall wasn't interfering. Now I can connect from phone to PC and messages are arriving.

Comment: @RBasniak Hi.. I am facing similar issue in receiving the result back to the c# client. May I know what you mean by creating an exception on firewall to all local ports ?